# Compare in CUDA without branching

Tags: c, performance, cuda, comparison, branchless

I am trying to implement the following function in CUDA:

```
int compare(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

I am currently using a pretty naive macro

```
#define CMP(X, Y) (((X) == (Y)) ? 0 : (((X) < (Y)) ? -1 : 1))
```

but I am wondering if it's causing divergence due to the branching. Is there any better way to implement this function in CUDA?

Comment: This is a misguided approach to optimization.  There are many questions like it on SO.  If you research any of those, you'll discover things like predication which the compiler will aggressively use to eliminate the need for branching in such a simple code.

Comment: I was not aware of techniques such as branch predication. Good to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a branch-less equivalent, that is:

```
(a > b) - (a < b)
```

This solves potential warp divergence.

In your code, `nvcc` compiler may eliminate divergence anyway, with usage of *branch predication*. But, even with this technique, some threds in warp may be inactive. You might observe this in *Thread Execution Efficiency*  column in NSight Visual Studio profiler for particular statement in your code.